# How do we detect a double click outside an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
this.div.click( function(e) {
   ...
});
```

I would like to listen for double clicks outside this element. I know that we can use blur() for clicks outside an element. But I would like to handle only double click events. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.dblclick()`](https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) event to listen to the double-click at the `body` level, and then use it's `target` attribute and [`.contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) to see if the click occurred within the div.

Something like this:

```
// div to check if dbl click did _not_ originate from
var mydiv = jQuery("#mydiv").get(0);

// listen to body for double clicks
$("body").dblclick(function(e) {
  // if click target does not fall within #mydiv
  if (mydiv !== e.target && $.contains(mydiv, e.target) !== true) {
    console.log("outside of mydiv");
  }  
});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/jakukocexe/edit?html,output) is a jsbin demo.

Comment: @henry The first condition is there because $.contains checks for descendants, not if it's two args are equal

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for some reason on my webpage and the event gets triggered several times for 1 double click. Should probably work on simpler websites though. I got loads of code.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to do this, by modifying `e.originalEvent`:

```
$( "#mydiv" ).dblclick(function(e) {
    e.originalEvent.inside = true;
});
$( "body" ).dblclick(function(e) {
    if( e.originalEvent.inside ) {
      console.log('inside');
    } else {
      console.log('outside');
    };
});
```

I have updated [Johnatan's Bin](http://jsbin.com/pujibajebo/1/edit?html,output). Think it should be faster.